# Update a struct element in a MapSet

Tags: elixir

I've matched the variable game with a MapSet composed of structs.
In the shell game returns

```
   iex(7)> game = Game.new
 #MapSet<[
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 1, color: nil, row: 1},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 1, color: nil, row: 2},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 1, color: nil, row: 3},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 2, color: nil, row: 1},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 2, color: nil, row: 2},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 2, color: nil, row: 3},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 3, color: nil, row: 1},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 3, color: nil, row: 2},
  %Tris.Coordinate{col: 3, color: nil, row: 3}
 ]>
```

The game MapSet is composed of 9 fixed elements. I would like just to update the color field for each individual Coordinate element. Something like : col: 1, row:1 color: "red" or in alternative col:1, row: 2, color: "blue". What is the best way to do it?  I don't want to add new elements but change the existing ones. The MapSet should be composed only of 9 Coordinate elements.

Answer (score 0):

A MapSet is immutable and you can't change its keys without removing and reinserting. To find an element based on a partial match requires iterating through the whole MapSet. Here's how to achieve this:

```
game
|> Enum.map(fn coord ->
  if coord.row == 1 && coord.col == 2 do
    %{coord | color: "red"}
  else
    coord
  end
end).
|> MapSet.new
```

I'm not sure why you're storing this in a MapSet in the first place, but you might want to consider storing this in a list (`[1, 2, ..., 9]`) or tuple (`{1, 2, ..., 9}`) or nested tuple (`{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}`).